# Equation simplification

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Given that:

```
X={{0,0,0,0,0,1} -> -2*a*f + 3*b*f*Cos[y] - a*f*Cos[x]*Cos[y] + Sqrt[3]*a*f*Cos[y]*Sin[x]
                    + Sqrt[3]*b*f*Sin[y] - Sqrt[3]*a*f*Cos[x]*Sin[y] - a*f*Sin[x]*Sin[y],
   {0,0,0,1,0,1} -> -f^2*Cos[x]*Cos[y] + Sqrt[3]*f^2*Cos[y]*Sin[x] 
                    - Sqrt[3]*f^2*Cos[x]*Sin[y] - f^2*Sin[x]*Sin[y]}
```

when I execute:

```
Map[Map[TrigFactor, Collect[#, {a, b, f}]] &, X]
```

I get the following output:

```
{{0,0,0,0,0,1} -> f * (-2*a - a*Cos[x-y] + 3*b*Cos[y] + Sqrt[3]*a*Sin[x-y] 
                  + Sqrt[3]*b*Sin[y]),
 {0,0,0,1,0,1} -> -2*f^2*Sin[Pi/6-x+y]}
```

But I want this:

```
{{0,0,0,0,0,1} -> -2*a*f - 2*a*f*Sin[Pi/6+x-y] + 6*b*f*Sin[Pi/6+y],
 {0,0,0,1,0,1} -> -2*f^2*Sin[Pi/6-x+y]}
```

Does this behavior is related to not applying `TrigFactor` recursively?

How can I solve this?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

`Map` trigfactor only to the second level in the expression:

```
    Map[Map[TrigFactor, Collect[#, {a, b, f}], {2}] &, X]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1} -> 
>   2 Sqrt[3] b f Cos[Pi/6 - y] +  a f (-2 - 2 Sin[Pi/6 - x + y]),
>  {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1} -> -2 f^2 Sin[Pi/6 - x + y]}
> ```

( I think your desired output expression is off.. )